# vh and vw not rendering small size/incorrectly

Tags: html, css

This is what I was HTML/CSSing out.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pcrjtmg6gjv2yc7/AAAw7GA8G-CTDFjOMqIUdqS_a?dl=0

[image]

and this is what I have managed hitherto.

[image]

Now the divs which display the search results are giving me trouble.

I am learning CSS and thought of using vh and vw .

So I proceeded like this:

The dimension of the psd file is 1100*1125

So one vh =11.25
and one vw=11

I laid out the outer design using the %age model.
Then for the result divs , I measure the height of the first one as 125 px.
Converting that,125/11=11.11vh

and so on.

But the end result is terribly awful !!Everything renders out very  little.I understand that it would be scaled down to my 768px height , but still it looks horribly small.

Please tell me what is wrong with my approach.

```
<html>   
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/main.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="sidebar">
      </div>
        <div class="box">
         <p>35 search results for "Preview"</p>
         <input type="text">

         <input type="checkbox"  id="checkboxOneInput"><label for="checkboxOneInput">Todos</label>
         <input type="checkbox"><label>Discussions</label>
         <input type="checkbox"><label>Files</label>
         <input type="checkbox"><label>Progress</label>
         <input type="checkbox"><label>TeamMembers</label>    
         <div class="display">        
            <div class="inner_display image">    
               <div class="image_one">
                  <img src="assets/images/bluei.png">
                  <p>17 July</p></div>    
                  <div class="image_two"><img src="assets/images/xlsx.png"></div>    
                  <div class="image_three">
                     <p>preview.timeline_v1.jpg</p>
                     <p>Attached to the comment timeline_wireframes by Bharat</p>
                     <p>DOWNLOAD</p>
                     <p>Download</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.sidebar {
   width:9.09%;
   height:100%;
   background:black;
   margin:0;
   position:fixed;
}    

.box {
   float:right;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width:90.91%;
   height:100%;
   background:#D3D3D3;
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:top;
   padding-left:2.5%;
   padding-right:2.5%;    
   overflow:auto;
}

.box p {    
   margin:0;
   height:4.44%;    
}

.box input[type=text] {    
   width:100%;
   height:4.44%;
   margin-top:1.77%;
   margin-bottom:0.88%;
}

.display {
   margin-top:2.66%;
   padding-left:2.72vw;
   margin-bottom:2.5%;
   border:solid;
   border-width:thin;
   background:white;    
}

.inner_display {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image {
   height:11.11vh;    
}

.image_one  {
   width:5.45vw;    
   margin-top:1.77vh;
   margin-bottom:1.77vh;    
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:top;
}

.image_one img {
   width:3.81vw;
   height:3.11vh;
}

.image_two {
   width:5.45vw;    
   margin-top:1.77vh;
   margin-bottom:1.77vh;    
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:top;       
}

.image_two img {
   height:3.55vh;
   width:3.63vw;    
}

.image_three {
   margin-top:1.77vh;
   margin-bottom:1.77vh;    
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:top;    
   font-size:1.6vh;
   line-height:0.5vh;    
}
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? As far as I can remember `viewport-height` and `viewport-width` have limited support.

Comment: Mozilla.
Uh..they are scaling fine with the page.So I guess vh and vw are supported.But they have been rendered so small initially that they are of no use

Comment: `1vh = 1 * viewport heigth / 100` -> `0.5vh = 0.5 * 1250px / 100 = 6,25 px`. Thats  why it is so small. The normal size of a paragraph is 18px.

Comment: @DomeTune
https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/
1vh of 40 cm=0.4 cm.
According to you it should be 0.2cm ?

Comment: @adawg Read my comment again please. For your example: `1vh = 1 * 40cm / 100 = 0.4cm` -> `0.5vh = 0.5 * 40cm / 100 = 0.2cm`. In your class `image_three` you have the `line-height: 0.5vh;`

Comment: Anh..OHkay.The text is not the only issue here.I never intended to use line height .Tried it just to make my text readable.The whole Inner_div is nasty as this is where I started my vh vw sojourn.
The pics on the left of the text are also smaller than what I intend them to be.

Comment: The only solution I am left with is now playing with the dimensions myself,to see what pleases the eye .But then they will not stick to the dimesnions of the photoshop file.

Comment: If you want the h/w ratio of the icons preserved, you may want to use the same unit for horizontal and vertical measurements. The one above "17 July" is supposed to be a circle, right? So try a size in `vmax` or `vmin` for both the width and the height.

Comment: @MrLister That is what I have done.Say the one above 17 july had a dimension of 35*35 in the psd of 1100*1125, then I have set that in my  CSS as 35/11*35/11.25.